# Jquery click function with button and text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello eveyone I'm trying to using click function.  When the user clicks the button, a second text will appear and the first one will be display none and then user clicks again using the same button this time third text will appear and the second text will be display and finally click the same button again fourth text will appear third one display none.

I have another button that user clicks this button the fourth text will be display none and the third text will appear and click again this button the third text will display none second text will appear and finally click this button second will diplay none the first text will appear. Here is my function:

```
 $("#slider1next").click(function () {

         var $next = $(".text:visible").hide().next();
         $next.length ? $next.show() : $(".text:first").show();

 });

 $("#slider2next").click(function () {

         var $next = $(".text:visible").hide().next();
         $next.length ? $next.show() : $(".text:first").show();

 });
```

​
Here is my html:

```
<button id="slider1next" >Clickme</button>
  <p class="text" id="first_one">This is the first text</p>
    <p class="text" id="second_one" style="display:none">This is the second text</p>
    <p class="text" id="third_one" style="display:none">This is the third text</p>
<p class="text" id="fourth_one" style="display:none">This is the four text</p>

<br/>
<button id="slider2next" >Clickme</button>
```

And also you can see there

http://jsfiddle.net/ganymedes/7kxAE/2/

Please help me

Comment: So you want that the second button has the opposite functionality of the other like that : http://jsfiddle.net/7kxAE/3/? I am just using .prev() instead of .next()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `prev` method and `:last` selector:

```
$("#slider1next").click(function() {
    var $next = $(".text:visible").hide().next();
    $next.length ? $next.show() : $(".text:first").show();
});

$("#slider2next").click(function() {
    var $prev = $(".text:visible").hide().prev();
    $prev.length ? $prev.show() : $(".text:last").show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dq6rf/

Comment: Thank you but when I click the second button you know the fourth hide then third appear, third hide and second appear but when I click again I dont want the first text hide I mean the first text like a constant text

Comment: Yes like that but for your query I click he firts button when I see "This the fourth text" then I click same button nothing will appear then I click the second button which is has prev property doesnt not get ant text could you look your query